# How to CrossValidate and GridCV multiclass-multioutput labels?

Tags: validation, scikit-learn, cross-validation, multilabel-classification

When I try :

```
: cross_val_score(r.model,r.y_test, r.test_pred, cv=3)

ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported
```

I even crated score() method for the model i.e.

```
 : r.model.score(r.y_test,r.test_pred)
 Out[177]: 0.13846153846153847

 : r.model.predict([r.ins[15]])
 : array([[105., 118., 103., 119.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   3.,   1.,   2.,   4.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])
```

still no way to handle multi-label(integer) cases..
Training and prediction works, it just seems Validation is handicapped !

Any ideas how to CV  multi-label(integer) data ?